# Is it possible to access a local printer using TCP/IP sockets in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, printing, tcp, udp

I know that PHP has it's own [PECL to do this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php), but I'm currently using PHP 5.4 and the `php_printer.dll` isn't compiled for this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PECL can have some old stuff on there, php_printer.dll is all but deprecated.
Also, as PHP is a scripting language, it's incredibly difficult to gain access to hardware functions (like a printer) directly. 
You are best off finding or writing printer access functions in something like C++, and running the script using system(); .
Best of luck!

Comment: I've done excatly that! I just execute "print" command from the "exec" function on Windows, and through it I can print documents :)

Answer (score 0):

Printing directly from PHP over TCP/IP sockets requires huge amount of work especially on windows environment without [Printer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php) extension or a nice library.

From the documentation:

> Windows users must enable php_printer.dll inside of php.ini in order
>   to use these functions. A DLL for this PECL extension is currently
>   unavailable.

So, you can try to download `php_printer.dll` precompiled binary for PHP 5.3 from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ and use that. Probably it will work with PHP 5.4 too. If not, you should [compile PHP from source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php) to use windows Printer extension.

Comment: I've tried that, and as I told "php_printer.dll" isn't compiled for PHP 5.4+ and by that I mean that PHP has changed alot since 5.2+ and even 5.3+, and that means that I will have to modify some php_printer.dll sources before compiling it, and I'm not quite qualified to do that.